Multithreaded Access on C Enum
I've found out that in C-Language a Enum is usually considered 4 Bytes.
If I have a multithreaded Application using a enum variable it might (even on 32-bit Processors) not be a atomic access, meaning it might not be written in one go and thread switches or multiple simultaneous read/write access might occur.
Now, my question is: Can I consider a enum read/write access atomic if it stores less then 1 Byte of memory?
For example:
typedef enum {
    Value0 = 0,
    Value1,
    Value2
} SomeEnumType

This enum only holds 3 values, which are assigned to numbers that are less than 1 Byte.
In case of 4 Bytes depending on the Processor it could be stored in 2 ways:
Bits:
00000000 00000000 00000000 <enum value>
or
<enum value> 00000000 00000000 00000000
If one byte can be considered atomic and the other 3 bytes will always be "0", could I consider the access to such enum to be atomic and therefore thread safe?
Because no matter where the when and how the processor access the enum it's always a valid value.
Im working on C99 Standard

Before the C23 standard, all enumerations are basically plain int types and values. There's no way around that.

I'd use an atomic int type and cast it to enum where necessary.

@Someprogrammerdude: An enumerated type is not an enumeration constant. An enumeration constant has type int. An enumerated type has a type that is compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type, the choice of which is implementation-defined. (C 2023 is expected to preclude bool and bit-precise integer types.)

You don't necessarily need to store enumerated constants in the enumerated type in which they are defined. You can store them in some other integer type as long as the value can be represented in that type. You can use enum as a handy mechanism for defining named values of type int.

There are a few flawed assumptions here.
First off, in C only bitfields store less than one byte. They are definitely not atomic. Typically, a bitfield write is implemented as a read-modify-write, where the modify part involves bitmasks.
Enums are not bitfields, even if you have only a handful of enumerators.
You are right that a 4 byte enum could be stored in those two ways; they're called big-endian and little-endian. Theoretically there are more options but no current CPU does that.
Even if it's a 4 byte value, access to the enum is not atomic and not thread safe.
(ignoring the standard for a moment, some CPU's support atomic access for aligned 4 byte access, but there's no need for your compiler to align that enum since it's not atomic)
Most problematic of all, you claim to be on C99. That would mean nothing is thread safe. Threads are introduced with C11.

OP does have a reasonable question in asking whether they can treat the object as atomic given that the value of the enumeration depends solely on a single byte of the representation; all the other bytes are always zero. Hypothetically, a C implementation might update a value by storing all one bits into the memory location and then storing the bytes of the new value, and this would conform to the C standard (both 1999 and later). However, in any practical C implementation, will any non-atomic change ever be observed in this situation where only a single byte matters?

@EricPostpischil: I think you're trying to say that "tearing" (reading some bytes of the old value, some bytes of the new value) is the only possible way in which this could fail on practical C implementations. The main concern I would expect here is an unaligned write that's mapped to two aligned read-modify-writes. Yes, one of those two will be idempotent in theory, but no practical compiler will eliminate that. And since it's a non-atomic non-synchronized write, the two aligned RMW's can both race with other threads. I.e. it could trash adjacent data.

"...you claim to be on C99. That would mean nothing is thread safe." What a silly thing to say. Any version of C with POSIX threads and careful design can be thread safe. Poorly-written code in C11 can be thread-unsafe. I understand that you and many others are pushing standard C without undefined behavior, and I generally support that. But simple statements like that are not helpful.


I've found out that in C-Language an Enum is usually considered 4 Bytes. If I have a multithreaded Application using an enum variable it might (even on 32-bit Processors) not be an atomic access,

Normally, and this since the beginning of C, an enum has been considered a synonym of int, in all aspects, as the most efficient way to handle an integer variable.  All things applicable to an enum indeed apply to an int.  But the question you ask is about how the access is done by the processor to an integer sized variable.  enums are 32 bit commonly in 32 bit machines, as ints are, and they normally are loaded and stored using a single bus access.  The case you explain about non-atomic integer reads is almost exclusively related to intel architectures that don't require integers to be aligned to a 32-bit boundary.  This normally facilitates the programming of assembler code, but almost no compiler at all does misalign a 32-bit integer because the access would require two bus accesses to read the two pieces of the integer.  This, which works on Intel machines, normally triggers an exception on others, and results in a requirement.
Well, once you said this, you can almost be sure that a 32-bit access in a 32-bit computer will be atomic (what is more atomic than single bus access.... let's see)  or not?
Well, not at all... because no memory access at all can also be done by the compiler.  If the compiler caches the value of a non volatile variable, it can remain in a register for a whole computation, if you don't specify the variable to be volatile and this means that all variables that are suspect of being accessed from several threads of execution must never be cached by the processor.  Atomic reading of a single bus access variable can be further complicated by cache lines (a complete cache line is read if some value is stored in main memory and the variable has already been used) so to consider an atomic read you must follow the guidelines of the virtual machine implementation specified in the C standard.
As you have been told in another answer, a bitfield access is never atomic, because holding the bus for exclusive access is out of scope in the C standard, but several cpus allow you to make a read-write-read accesses in atomic ways, but again, with different flavours (some, like ARM, don't allow you to block the bus for exclusive access, but indicate that the atomic access has been impossible when a collision is detected, so you can retry the operation, while others allow you to block the bus, and grant the cpu exclusive access for a short period of time --two or three bus access cycles)  Anyway, all these operations are out of scope of the C standard, but are common in the implementation of spinlocks, semaphores or rendezvous.
If you are in doubt, the best approach is

study the documentation of the processor to see if a 32-bit integer can need several accesses to be read.
check if this is actually what you need.  Atomic reading is only required when some thread can write a new value to a memory cell while another is actually reading.  If you are in doubt, use a semaphore or a spinlock to wait for it.  In that case, you can trust that alignment will save you reducing the access to a single bus request.  But if you don't know, the better the safer.

It's not clear what is your actual problem, but today's computers don't make simple bus accesses to get memory.  You need to know if both threads run in the same processor.  Then a context switch is required to switch from one thread to another (well, this can happen if you have interrupts enabled, but never to make a 32-bit read from memory under the same instruction, interrupts only happen between instructions). You can have both threads running in two cores of the same CPU.  In that case, normally you can get a vad value if two instructions access the same memory in two different threads of the processor pipeline.  Pipelines with instruction reordering use to mangle bus accesses in order to get the more number of instructions per cycle.  This can destroy the data if the data lives in memory locations that require two bus accesses and run in different threads in the same pipeline.  this happens only on unaligned data (which normally is not the case)
If there are two threads running in cores not sharing the same memory, then a cache line invalidation is required to force the CPU to access main memory. I'd use a spinlock in that case to avoid interspersing assembler code into the C code.

Jonathan, thanks for the revision but you have been a bit pecky with it.  Correcting rendez-vous (a french pair of words) into rendezvous (a single word) is excessive. I'm not english parlant (another frenchism) and I thank you for the corrections, but don't go so far.  Thanks anyway :)

The issue of thread safety can be complicated. There are millions of lines of code that are running the world today that are written using assumptions that are not portable across architectures or even versions of compilers. This is the so-called undefined behavior problem. Raph Levien writes about three "camps" of programmers: Unportable, Semi-portable, and Standard C. He claims (correctly, IMO) that the vast majority of C programmers today are in the semi-portable camp. This means that most programmers are writing code that make assumptions that are not really portable.
Why do they ... um ... we do that? Because we don't need our code to be portable. My product is only supported on a two platforms (X86 and Sparc) and the chances of porting it to a third platform different enough to make a difference is pretty much zero. So we make our assumptions about memory alignment, bus cycles, cache usage, etc, and our product works.
But we are living on borrowed time. Compiler writers are producing more aggressive optimizers to produce ever-more efficient machine code, and it's only a matter of time before our product gets stuck, not only on a set of architectures, but also on a version of compiler that we can't grow past without significant changes to our codebase.
So, the real answer to the question you asked is: it depends on what architectures you want to run on, and how portable you want to be. For example, if you are confident you'll only ever be run on X86 and ARM, then you can establish some coding conventions that will guarantee thread-safe access to your enum variable without using mutexes. You'll join the ranks of semi-portable programmers.
Specifically, you'll need to make sure that any such variable (not just enums) are aligned to the bus width of your target machines. (You might want to double that to make your code safer for hardware upgrades.) You might need to declare the variable volatile to make sure it doesn't get optimized to a register or even completely optimized away. And be aware that any kind of read/modify/write operation needs special attention -- make sure your target architecture supports the kind of bus locking that is needed, and potentially include memory fences. (A full tutorial on this is way beyond the scope of a SO answer.)
Or you could just be safe and properly use a mutex. This might lower your performance due to thread contention, but it means you don't have to worry about all those issues.
